# flutter: after navigate throughing a error Failed assertion

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, flutter-routes

when my all variable is null then my "initialRoute" is set on LoginPage. now when I am trying to login then I am getting this bellow error.

`Failed assertion: line 3002 pos 7: '!pageBased || isWaitingForExitingDecision': A page-based route cannot be completed using imperative api, provide a new list without the corresponding Page to Navigator.pages instead.`

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cwc/OnBoard/landing_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/OnBoard/login_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/EventProviderPage/event_provider_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'ApiManager/api_magager.dart';
import 'ApiManager/preference.dart';
import 'EcommercePages/ProviderPages/address_provider.dart';
import 'EcommercePages/ProviderPages/cart_provider.dart';
import 'EcommercePages/ProviderPages/fav_provider.dart';
import 'OnBoard/PackageProviderPage/package_provider_page.dart';
import 'OnBoard/enter_details.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

Widget initialRoute = HomePage();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var token = await Preferences.loadData("token");
  var name = await Preferences.loadData("name");
  var zipCode = await Preferences.loadData("zipCode");
  var city = await Preferences.loadData("city");
  var state = await Preferences.loadData("state");
  var country = await Preferences.loadData("country");
  var status = await Preferences.loadData("status");
  var packageCost = await Preferences.loadData("packageCost");
  var image = await Preferences.loadData("image");
  var password = await Preferences.loadData("password");
  var uuid = await Preferences.loadData("uuid");
  var packageName = await Preferences.loadData("packageName");
  var eventDiscount = await Preferences.loadData("eventDiscount");

  Stripe.publishableKey =
      "pk_test_51JFOxZEpHAy36lvUnZFTbStWbmVHp4APAHAzMIYLdn5d0K8Ao3FGtd5dGIy3vDadtgb9HmVuvLwyke67i1PDnFwV00pLRE0ujx";
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
// Preferences.clearData('token');
  // print("name -- $name");
  print("zipCode -- $zipCode");
  print("city -- $city");
  print("state -- $state");
  print("country -- $country");
  print("token -- $token");
  print("status -- $status");
  print("packageCost -- $packageCost");
  print("image -- $image");
  print("password -- $password");
  print("uuid -- $uuid");
  print("packageName -- $packageName");
  print("eventDiscount -- $eventDiscount");

  if (token == null || token == "null") {
    initialRoute = LoginPage();
  } else if (token != null || token != "null") {
    print("status2 -- $status");
    if ((name == null || name == "null") ||
        (zipCode == null || zipCode == "null") ||
        (city == null || city == "null") ||
        (state == null || state == "null") ||
        (country == null || country == "null") ||
        (password == null || password == "null")) {
      initialRoute = EnterDetails();
    } else if ((token != null || token != "null") &&
        (name != null || name != "null")) {
      print("status1 -- $status");
      if ((status == null || status == "null" || status == "inactive")) {
        initialRoute = LandingPage();
      }
    }
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ApiManager apiManager = ApiManager();
  var token = "";
  var name = "";
  var zipCode = "";
  var city = "";
  var state = "";
  var country = "";
  var status = "";
  var packageCost = "";
  var image = "";
  var password = "";
  var uuid = "";
  var packageName = "";
  var eventDiscount = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    userData();
  }

  userData() async {
    token = await Preferences.loadData("token");
    name = await Preferences.loadData("name");
    zipCode = await Preferences.loadData("zipCode");
    city = await Preferences.loadData("city");
    state = await Preferences.loadData("state");
    country = await Preferences.loadData("country");
    status = await Preferences.loadData("status");
    packageCost = await Preferences.loadData("packageCost");
    image = await Preferences.loadData("image");
    password = await Preferences.loadData("password");
    uuid = await Preferences.loadData("uuid");
    packageName = await Preferences.loadData("packageName");
    eventDiscount = await Preferences.loadData("eventDiscount");
    setState(() {});
// Preferences.clearData('token');
    // print("name -- $name");
    print("zipCode -- $zipCode");
    print("city -- $city");
    print("state -- $state");
    print("country -- $country");
    print("token -- $token");
    print("status -- $status");
    print("packageCost -- $packageCost");
    print("image -- $image");
    print("password -- $password");
    print("uuid -- $uuid");
    print("packageName -- $packageName");
    print("eventDiscount -- $eventDiscount");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => CartProvider(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => FAVProvider(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => AddressProvider(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => EventProvider(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => MembershipPackageProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'CWC(Khushi)',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            routerConfig: GoRouter(initialLocation: '/', routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: '/',
                builder: (_, __) {
                  print("router1::::");
                  return initialRoute;
                },
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                      path: 'events',
                      builder: (_, a) {
                        print("router:::::");
                        if (token == null || token == "null") {
                          return LoginPage();
                        } else if (token != null || token != "null") {
                          print("status2 -- $status");
                          if ((name == null || name == "null") ||
                              (zipCode == null || zipCode == "null") ||
                              (city == null || city == "null") ||
                              (state == null || state == "null") ||
                              (country == null || country == "null") ||
                              (password == null || password == "null")) {
                            return EnterDetails();
                          } else if ((token != null || token != "null") &&
                              (name != null || name != "null")) {
                            print("status1 -- $status");
                            if ((status == null ||
                                status == "null" ||
                                status == "inactive")) {
                              return LandingPage();
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        return Container(
                          child: Text("deepak:: $a"),
                        );
                      }),
                ],
              ),
              // home:VideoComponentPurple(),
            ])));
  }
}
```